# basic if statment brain fart HTML javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

trying to learn javascript for the first time i am stuck on an issue involving an if statement I want the user to be able to put in the text a letter then have the computer say whether what he put in was right or wrong when I run this it usually skips some part of the if statement. this could be because I'm using the != symbol but I don't know below is the code to show you what I am working with I hope I can get you some help!

```js
document.getElementById("Submit").onclick = function(){
    var a = "'a', 'b', 'c'";
    var enter = document.getElementById("text").value;
    a.toString();

    if (a == enter) {
        alert("congrats");
    }
    else if(enter == null) {
        alert("you put nothing");
    }
    else if (enter != a) {
        alert("wrong try again")
    }
    else {
        alert("End of if statment")    
    }    
}
```

```html
<form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id = "text" name="firstname">
</form> 
<button type="button" id ="Submit">Submit!</button>
```

Comment: And what's the expected behavior which is not happening? (describe it)

Comment: The letter should be either a, b or c in order to show "congrats"?

Comment: What happens if you enter `'a', 'b', 'c'` ?

Comment: Some notes: `a.toString();` this has absolutely no effect. `if(enter == null)` this will never happen. `else{` this will never happen. Other than that, did you enter "'a', 'b', 'c'"?

Comment: `a.toString();` does nothing.... and `enter` is never going to equal `null`

Comment: Is the text they entered supposed to match `'a', 'b', 'c'` as one entire string?

Also you don't need to use `.toString()`, it's already a string

Comment: And `enter` will never be `null`

Instead, look for `enter === ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `a` as a string with value `'a', 'b', 'c'` so it is a string with some letters and the `'` symbol.

If you want to check if what the user entered is one of those letters declared by you (let's say `a`, `b` or `c`)...

You should (for your attempt) declare it as an array like this: `var a = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in order to see if what the user entered is a letter inside the array.

See below snippet

```js
document.getElementById("SubmitArrayVersion").onclick = function() {
  var aArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // array version

  var enter = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if (aArray.indexOf(enter) !== -1) {
    alert("congrats");
  } else if (!enter) {
    alert("you put nothing");
  } else {
    alert("wrong try again")
  }

}
```

```html
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id="text" name="firstname">
</form>
<button type="button" id="SubmitArrayVersion">Submit! (Array version)</button>
```

Comment: although it works, it doesn't seem to be a good idea since you can enter `,` or `'` or even a whitespace and the code will say "congrats", probably what he asker wants is to match a single letter, like `a` OR `b` OR `C`

Comment: @CalvinNunes agree 100% with you... that's why  I updated the answer in order to be more accurate according to the OP intent. Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: @CalvinNunes You have misunderstood it. He want to enter the whole string `abc` and want to check. Not a single character. The OP has problems in understanding the string comparisions.

Comment: actually, this is pretty on the money thank you very much it works but it will only check a and j (my array consists of the whole alphabet).

Comment: @WillSanefski you're welcome. Then you just need to fill the array with the letters you want to include. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to change your a variable. Now you have an array(3 different values a,b,c), or just weird string( 'a','b','c'), I'm not sure about this. It shuold look like this:

> var a = "abc";

Now, your "congrats" alert should work, as it can actually try to weak-compare these two values succesfully.

Next step you have to make, is to change null for "".

> else if (enter == "")

That's because this value(no input) is actually undefined value, not null, so with "null" there is no way to compare this.

These are just basic primitive variables types. For more information I would reccomend to read this: [Read That Book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)

Answer (score 0):

It will be correct when the user enters `'a', 'b', 'c'` into the input field.

If you try the code below

```js
document.getElementById("Submit").onclick = function(){
    var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var enter = document.getElementById("text").value;

    if (array[0] == enter){
        alert("congrats");
    }
    else if(enter == null){
        alert("you put nothing");
    }
    else if (enter != array[0]){
        alert("wrong try again")
    }
    else{
        alert("End of if statment")

    }

}
```

```html
<form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id = "text" name="firstname">
</form> 
<button type="button" id ="Submit">Submit!</button>
```

That will alert congrats when a is entered into the input as it is checking the first element of the array (assuming if you have worked with arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your program to print out success when the user puts in either the single letter a, b, or c this should work.

```js
document.getElementById("Submit").onclick = function() {

  var enter = document.getElementById("text").value;

  if ('a' === enter || 'b' === enter || 'c' === enter) {
    alert("congrats");
  } else if (enter == "") {
    alert("you put nothing");
  } else if('a' != enter || 'b' != enter || 'c' != enter) {
    alert("wrong try again");
  }


}
```

```html
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="text" name="firstname">
</form>
<button type="button" id="Submit">Submit!</button>
```

In the first if statement I used the || operator to distinguish between different conditions, the expression in the if statement will convert to `true` if enter is either the string a, b, or c.

Then the second part checks if enter is empty, the third part is kinds obsolete because we already know that enter is not a, b, or c because we checked it in the first if statement but I left it in for reference.

So:

```
  } else if('a' != enter || 'b' != enter || 'c' != enter) {
    alert("wrong try again");
  }
```

Could be rewritten to:

```
else {
   alert("wrong try again");
}
```